# Exception in GWT Elemental Simple Example

Tags: gwt, gwt-elemental

I am attempting to run the GWT Elemental example (from the GWT 2.5.1 repository) and it is giving me an exception at runtime. I had to make a couple of changes to the code in order to get this to run, which I am guessing is a result of changes to Elemental that are not reflected in the example code. Here is the code, with my changes noted:

```java
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
  final ButtonElement btn = getDocument().createButtonElement();
  btn.setInnerHTML("w00t?");
  btn.getStyle().setColor("red");
  getDocument().getBody().appendChild(btn);
  final DivElement div = getDocument().createDivElement();
  getDocument().getBody().appendChild(div);
  EventListener listener = new EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event evt) {
      final XMLHttpRequest xhr = getWindow().newXMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.setOnload(new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event evt2) {
          div.setInnerHTML(xhr.getResponseText());
        }
      });
      xhr.open("GET", "/snippet.html");
      xhr.send();
      getWindow().setTimeout(new TimeoutHandler() { // *** changed from "new Window.TimerCallback()"
        @Override
        public void onTimeoutHandler() { // *** changed from "public void fire()"
          getWindow().alert("timeout fired");
        }
      }, 1000);
      btn.removeEventListener(Event.CLICK, this, false);
    }
  };
  btn.addEventListener(Event.CLICK, listener, false);
}
```

The original code is here: [ElementalExample.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.5/elemental/examples/simple/src/elemental/example/client/ElementalExample.java).

The exception is occurring on the line: `btn.addEventListener(Event.CLICK, listener, false);`, and appears to be caused by a null object in one of the JavaScript libraries. If I comment out the `btn.addEventListener()` call then the page is shown in the browser, with the button (although it is non-functional, of course, with no event listener). Has anyone else tried to run this example? If so, do you have any pointers for running in the the latest release of GWT?

Here's the stack trace:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (String) : Invoking an instance method on a null instance
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.createJavaScriptException(ModuleSpace.java:80)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.createJavaScriptException(ModuleSpace.java:64)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:60)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
 at elemental.js.dom.JsElementalMixinBase$.addEventListener$(JsElementalMixinBase.java)
 at com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject$.elemental_html_ButtonElement_addEventListener(JavaScriptObject.java)
 at org.greatlogic.elementalfile.client.ElementalFileEntryPoint.onModuleLoad(ElementalFileEntryPoint.java:48)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:406)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

(Note that I have pasted the code into my own project, and hence the `org.greatlogic.elementalfile.client.ElementalFileEntryPoint` classname).

Comment: I faced a similar issue. Could not execute both samples under elemental "simple and silvercoment". I am guessing lib inconsistency. I might try out building everything out of gwt trunk and try again. Will update if i get across it.

Comment: Thanks SSR ... I tried creating an `InputElement` and setting the `Onchange` event handler - this failed with the same 'null instance' error.

Comment: > Caveats
> > Elemental is a work in progress. Due to the nature of it being
> auto-generated from IDL specifications, and those specifications for
> HTML5 changing rapidly over time, there are no unit tests for
> generated code, and usage of bleeding edge HTML5 are untested and may
> break.
> > Elemental also introduces a new set of native JS collections which are
> not interoperable with Java Collections.
> > Currently, Elemental is generated from the WebKit IDL files and
> contains many references to vendor-prefixed browser extensions. Using
> these draft-spec extensions may result in code

Comment: Yep, I've read the Google documentation for Elemental, and I understand that it's not guaranteed to work at all. I'm just hoping that someone will have something constructive to suggest here!

Comment: Some parts of elemental are probably updated as the browser specification change quite rapidly. AFAIK Elemental hasn't been updated for some time (I found some inconsistencies myself). Best thing is to create an issue in the issue tracker. I guess once elemental is re-built from updated IDL specifications these kind of bugs will get fixed automatically.